# How to augment a module from another "plugin" module in Typescript

Tags: typescript

If I type a module called "foo", like so:

```
declare module "foo" {
    interface App {
        bar: boolean;
    }

    namespace foo {}

    function foo(): App;

    export = foo;
}
```

How can I add a new property to the `App` interface when another module called `foo-plugin` is imported?

```
declare module "foo-plugin" {
    interface App {
        additional: string;
    }
}
```

I've tried the pattern described in https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-plugin-d-ts.html but it doesn't work, it only sees the `bar` property.

If I make the App interface top-level, the declarations are merged, but without the need to import `foo-plugin`.

This is what happens with chai-as-promised and sinon-chai.  This code compiles but of course throws an exception, since `eventually` is undefined.  Is it some sort of Typescript limitation and has to be accepted?

```
import { expect } from 'chai';

describe('Dummy', () => {
    it('passes', () => {
        expect('foo').to.eventually.equal(5);
    });
});
```

Thanks..

Comment: Use the same package name on your extension `declare module "foo" {`

Answer (score 5):

See here an [example with axios](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41533856/340760)

Basically on your plugin call it the same name as the module you want to extend

```
declare module "foo" { // foo-plugin
    interface App {
        additional: string;
    }
}
```

[Declaration Merging on TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Comment: thanks, I can actually augment the "foo" module using the style above, but I can get it to compile (and have Intellisense as well) without actually importing "foo-plugin".  It's probably some Typescript limitation (I'm new to TS)

Also, 100% soundness is not a design goal of TS.

SInce chai-plugins do this as well, I'll probably just concede. :-D

Comment: **Important note**: `declare module foo` is NOT the same as `declare module "foo"`. Had me puzzled for some time. (with the quotes, it tries to resolve the module to existing module matches; without, it assumes you're declaring a whole new module/namespace)